# Request to server each N seconds after flag

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a specific case. The first thing I do is request the Index.DB. After I got the taskId from it, I need to start asking the server every 5 seconds. And stop doing this on a specific flag. How can i do that properly with hooks?

I'tried to use useInterval hook like this: 
https://github.com/donavon/use-interval;
But when i set it in useEffect causes consistent error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

```js
const Page = () => {
    const [task, setTask] = useState({})

    const isLoaded = (task.status === 'fatal');

    const getTask = (uuid: string) => {
        fetch(`${TASK_REQUEST_URL}${uuid}`)
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(json => {
                        setTask(json.status)
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        Storage.get('taskId')
         .then(taskId => {
             if (!taskId) {
             Router.push('/');
          }
         useInterval(() => getTask(taskId), 5000, isTaskStatusEqualsSomthing)
         })
    }, []);


    return (
        <p>view</p>
    );
};
```

I also tried to play around native setInterval like this

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        Storage.get('taskId')
         .then(taskId => {
             if (!taskId) {
             Router.push('/');
          }
         setInterval(() => getTask(taskId), 5000)
         })

    }, []);
```

But in this case i don't know how to clearInterval and also code looks dirty.

Comment: Which react version  are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. You just need to configure your setInterval within `.then` callback like

```
useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    Storage.get('taskId')
     .then(taskId => {
         if (!taskId) {
            Router.push('/');
         else {
            timer = setInterval(() => getTask(taskId), 5000)
         }
      }

     })
     return () => {clearInterval(timer)}
}, []);
```

The reason, first approach doesn't work for you is because you cannot call a hook conditionally or in useEffect as you did for `useInterval`

Comment: DO you mean to say that it is conditionally in a way that either then or catch can run hence its breaking the rules of hooks. Can't we use Promise.finally? It will run unconditionally.

Comment: Thats wrong solution. How can i clearInterval on flag then? If (isLoaded) { ... ?}

Comment: clearInterval is run when the component unmounts, and if you have set the timer variable set which it will be once you receive the taskId, it will work